# SFTP Namespace with phpseclib installed manually

Tags: composer-php, phpseclib

I am trying to connect using SFTP (phpseclib) with a manual installation. That's the very first time I'm using namespaces so I don't know if what I'm doing is the way I have to.

I did download phpseclib from GitHub as ZIP and put it in /home/libs_web/php/class/phpseclib3

After that I used this code (just as example) :

```
require('/home/libs_web/php/class/phpseclib3/Net/SFTP.php');
use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;

$sftp = new SFTP('localhost');
$sftp->login('username', 'password');
```

As mentioned here but with an include on top : https://phpseclib.com/docs/sftp

Here is my error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'phpseclib3\Net\SSH2' not found in /home/libs_web/php/class/phpseclib3/Net/SFTP.php:52

It seems like my Namespace doesn't work correctly. I do not use autoloader, composer, and tried to set the working directory to /home/libs_web/php/class/phpseclib3/ & /home/libs_web/php/class/.

Don't know what to do more. If I include the file /Net/SSH2.php I'll have another error about another file. I think this isn't the proper way to work.

Could you please provide some help ?

Answer (score 1):

phpseclib3 is best installed with Composer. eg. on the CLI do `composer init; composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0`. You'd also put `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of your file

If you wanted to do something like make your source code available for people to download and make it work on shared hosts were CLI access might not be available I guess you could do Composer and then upload the vendor/ directory by itself or include it with your zip file or whatever.

Comment: Any solution if we don't want to use composer ? I want to download the library and use it. I don't like to have an automated system which downloads and installs things in an uncontrolled way.

Comment: @NetVicious - you could probably run composer locally, generate a vendor directory and an autoload.php and then put that into your project. So you'd still run composer but instead of *everyone* having to run Composer upon checking the project out it'd be ran just *once* and you could verify everything Composer did on the one time you did run it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I went back and I used phpseclib v2 which doesn't needs the composer thingy for people who do not want to battle with dependencies as we all did looong time ago.